# How to wrap a custom content page with HTML tags?

Tags: panels, theming

I have a mini-panel in which I add custom content panes. I would like to turn these content panes into buttons. I am able to apply some CSS to turn them into a block, by adding a css class via the "CSS properties" option in each pane's settings. But how can I make a link out of them?

There is no option to add HTML around a pane. And I really want the entire pane to be a link, not just the stuff in it. I could artificially insert HTML into the pane to create a link-block that would fill up all the space, but then I'd have to create other CSS properties to apply to this element, it would just be cumbersome.

I'm still on Drupal 6. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mabye [this](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/knobo/2376371) is what you want. You create a required context to your panel, then you choose the panel style to be "Linked". Then your panel will be rendered as &lt;a href="/node/n"&gt;PANELCONTENT&lt;/a&gt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you put an `<a>` tag inside the pane, and then with CSS give it a `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`, effectively filling the mini-pane?

To be specific, your html inside the pane would look like:

```
<a class="mini-pane-link" href="#">This Is A Link</a>
```

And your CSS would look like:

```
a.mini-pane-link {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

(You might want/need to put a few extra selectors in front of the `a.mini-pane-link`)